# get selected marker google maps api 3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in the following code generated an undetermined number of markers, this works well.

```
for(i=0;i<idr.length;i++){
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]);
m[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: LatLng,
    icon: image,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    val: idr[i] 
});
```

}

I want to get the properties of the corresponding marker when the mouse passes over this

This does not apply for you should create a function for each marker and can not be that many
This function only access the first marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(m[0], "click", function(e) {
       var latitud = e.latLng.lat();
       alert(latitud);
```

});

Answer (score 2):

use **`this`** inside the callback to get access to the current marker(**`m[i]`** will not work there, because it will always refer to the last created marker)

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(m[i], 'mouseover', function() {
        alert(this.val)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<idr.length;i++){
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]);
m[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: LatLng,
    icon: image,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    val: idr[i] 
});  
   google.maps.event.addListener(m[i], 'mouseover', function() {
        //Do stuff
    });
}
```

The above is how I would do it.

Comment: How do i get variable?

Comment: i would switch m[i] to "var marker" and pass marker into your listener and perform operations on marker  inside the addlistener